# iOS NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges froze main thread

Tags: ios, core-data

1. Use `NSFetchedResultsController` as the data source for `UITableView`. It is created with main context (`persistentContainer.viewContext`).
2. Execute batch delete using background context
3. Merge changes into main context to update UI. (**This is the problem. It freezes main thread**).

Here are the codes:

```
let mainContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
let taskContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
taskContext.perform {            
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MyItem")
    fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = false
    let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    batchDeleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs
    do {
        let result = try taskContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest) as? NSBatchDeleteResult
        let objectIDArray = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID]
        let changes = [NSDeletedObjectsKey : objectIDArray]

        /****below line of codes is the problem, it blocks main thread****/ 
        NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes as [AnyHashable : Any], into: [mainContext])

    } catch {
        print("Error batch delete items: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Is there any way to **avoid blocking main thread** in this situation? Please help. Thanks

Comment: try to do merging inside of `mainContext.perform { ... }`